# Can't access External url from Swagger

Tags: java, spring-boot, redirect, swagger, http-redirect

I configured Swagger in my project and it handles GET, POST and DELETE requests normally. However, in my project, clicking on one of these requests requires redirecting to another web resource, for example, *https://www.google.com/*. Swagger does not allow me to do this either by the methods:

```
public String testUrl = "https://www.google.com/";

@GetMapping("/RedirectView")
public RedirectView redirectView() {
    return new RedirectView(testUrl);
}

@GetMapping("/ResponseEntity")
public ResponseEntity<Object> responseEntity() throws URISyntaxException {
    URI uri = new URI(testUrl);
    HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    httpHeaders.setLocation(uri);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(httpHeaders, HttpStatus.SEE_OTHER);
}

@GetMapping(value = "/HttpServletResponse")
public void httpServletResponse(HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse) throws IOException {
    httpServletResponse.sendRedirect(testUrl);
}
```

In response to these methods it sends me an error:
**Code:** *Undocumented*
**Details:** *TypeError: Failed to fetch*
After opening the page code, I saw the following error in the console:
**Access to fetch at 'https://www.google.com/' (redirected from 'http://localhost:8080/HttpServletResponse') from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.**
I tried to solve the problem with CORS, even turned it off, but nothing seems to help me(

Comment: from what i know, swagger is a specification how to describe APIs.. Are you talking about server/client lib that was generated from a swagger spec?

Comment: @leberknecht yes, I'm writing code, one of the functions of which is to redirect to another page on the Internet. I can't navigate to another page while Swagger is required in my project.